# Output the average values of binned columns in Excel VBA

Tags: performance, beginner, vba, excel

This code is meant to run through a column of values, bin the values based on specified ranges, then output the average value of each bin.  The problem is the code is running quite slowly (approximately 30 min for around 100000 values).  I am definitely a beginner at coding and was hoping there was some way to speed this code along.

```
Sub BinValues()
'binns seperation distance values for the creation of variogram

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim Cell As Object
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim rng As Range
'define range before running
Set rng = Range("A1:A105570")
Dim K, n, L As Integer
'n is equal to the number of lags
'L is the lag size
n = 12
L = 600
For K = L To (n * L) Step 600
    For Each Cell In rng
    Dim min As Integer
    min = K - L
    'upper bound exclusive and lower bound inclusive
        If Cell.Value >= min And Cell.Value < K Then
            If R1 Is Nothing Then
                Set R1 = Range(Cell.Address)
            Else
                Set R1 = Union(R1, Range(Cell.Address))
            End If
            Cells((K / L), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Average(R1)     
        End If  

    Next
    Set R1 = Nothing
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Data belongs in an Array

A worksheet *looks* like a grid of data, but there's an **enourmous** amount of overhead sitting behind it. **Every** time you do **anything** to a spreadsheet, events fire, formulas calculate and a million other things happen behind the scenes.

Working with Ranges is computationally expensive, and you're doing it N*105,570*2 times.

Instead, what you want is an `Array`. An `Array` is just a grid of data laid out in memory. Because it is *just* data there are no overheads, and so you can read/write to it about a Million times faster.

You can create an `Array` by reading in a range, like so:

```
Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = Range("A1:A105570")

Dim dataArray As Variant
dataArray = dataRange.Value
```

And now, the value in `"A1"` is in `dataArray(1, 1)`, `"A2"` in `dataArray(2, 1)` etc.

**Let's re-write your code to use an Array:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BinValues()
    'binns seperation distance values for the creation of variogram

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = Range("A1:A105570")

    Dim dataArray As Variant
    dataArray = dataRange.Value

    Const NUM_LAGS As Long = 12
    Const LAG_SIZE As Long = 600

    Dim minValue As Double
    Dim maxValue As Double
    Dim lagCounter As Long
    Dim ix As Long

    Dim elementValue As Double
    Dim elementSum As Double
    Dim numElements As Double
    Dim elementAverage As Double

    For lagCounter = 1 To NUM_LAGS

        minValue = (lagCounter - 1) * LAG_SIZE
        maxValue = (lagCounter * LAG_SIZE) - 1

        numElements = 0
        elementSum = 0
        For ix = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)
            elementValue = dataArray(ix, 1)
            If elementValue >= minValue And elementValue <= maxValue Then
                numElements = numElements + 1
                elementSum = elementSum + elementValue
            End If
        Next ix

        elementAverage = elementSum / numElements
        Cells(lagCounter, 5) = elementAverage

    Next lagCounter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

That alone should take your runtime from 1/2 an hour to a couple of seconds (if that).

Comment: thank you that worked wonderfully.  Now I will try to piggy back on this post.  I have a code nearly identical to the first I posted that averages all the values in column two that correspond with the bins in column 1 using the selection offset.  I have commented in this portion of the code to my original post.  I am having trouble figuring out how I can do the same with the code you provided.

Comment: @zanwigz 2 suggestions. 1, don't change the question after the fact, by all means post a [follow-up](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c) instead. 2, just post the **entire** thing. The more code you show us, the more we can link things together and restructure them.

Comment: Follow Zak's advice.  I reworked an application (not mine) that way and it literally took processing down from 10 hours to under 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

**Limit data**

the range `Range("A1:A105570")` would have subsequent loops iterate over 105570 cells every time

since you're dealing with numbers it'd be faster to consider non blank cells filled with numbers only

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A105570").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
```

---

**Do in loops only what actually varies in them**

so

- `Dim min As Integer` must be taken outside both `For K = L...` and `For Each Cell...`
  loops
- `min = K - L` must be taken outside `For K = L...` loop
- `Cells((K / L), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Average(R1)` must be taken outside `For Each cell...` loop and placed right after `Next cell` ans substituting `Set R1 = Nothing` with:

      `If Not R1 Is Nothing Then
          Cells((K / L), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Average(R1)
      Else
          Set R1 = Nothing
      End If`

---

**Avoid unnecessary IF statements**

the following piece of code

```
For Each Cell In rng
    ....
    If Cell.Value >= min And Cell.Value < K Then
        If R1 Is Nothing Then
            Set R1 = Range(Cell.Address)
        Else
            Set R1 = Union(R1, Range(Cell.Address))
        End If
        Cells((K / L), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Average(R1)     
    End If  
Next
Set R1 = Nothing
```

could be refactored like follows

```
    Set R1 = rng(1, 1).Offset(, 1) '<--| set R1 to a dummy "invalid" range
    For Each cell In rng
        'upper bound exclusive and lower bound inclusive
        If cell.value >= min And cell.value < K Then Set R1 = Union(R1, cell) '<--| go with union without worrying about R1 being empty
    Next cell
    Set R1 = Intersect(R1, Columns(1)) '<-- intersect R1 with "valid" column
```

---

**Miscellanea**

- beware that coding like:

  ```
  Dim K, n, L As Integer
  ```

  stands for:

  ```
  Dim K As Variant, n As Variant, L As Integer
  ```

  since without explicit type declaration after any variable has the compiler consider it implicitly as of `Variant` type
- use `Long` type instead of `Integer` one

  it doesn't "cost" significantly in terms of memory and is much more appropriate when dealing with excel UI rows number since `Integer` type ranges from -32768 to 32767 while worksheet rows can reach up to 65,536 (till Excel 2003) or nearly 1 million (from Excel 2007 on)!

---

**Summary #1**

as for all what above a possible refactoring of your code could be the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub BinValues2()
    'binns seperation distance values for the creation of variogram

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim cell As Object
    Dim R1 As Range, rng As Range
    Dim K As Long, min As Long, n As Long, L As Long

    'define range before running
    Set rng = Range("A1:A105570").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| limit data to relevant ones

    n = 12 'n is equal to the number of lags
    L = 600 'L is the lag size
    For K = L To (n * L) Step L
        min = K - L
        Set R1 = rng(1, 1).Offset(, 1) '<--| set R1 to a dummy "invalid" range
        For Each cell In rng
            'upper bound exclusive and lower bound inclusive
            If cell.value >= min And cell.value < K Then Set R1 = Union(R1, cell) '<--| go with union without worrying about R1 being empty
        Next cell
        Set R1 = Intersect(R1, Columns(1)) '<-- intersect R1 with "valid" column
        If Not R1 Is Nothing Then
            Cells((K / L), 5) = WorksheetFunction.Average(R1)
        Else
            Set R1 = Nothing
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

---

**The BIG JUMP: Use Excel built-in data manipulation**

All what above leads (hopefully) to better coding habits and some significant speed increment, but the big jump comes with the use of excel built in data manipulation functions, namely [`Autofilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method of `Range` object

---

**Use With ... End With blocks**

this not only shortens code typing (thus increasing code readability and decreases typos probability) but also reduces objects memory accesses, especially effective when loops are in the game

---

**Summary #2**

`Autofilter()` and `With...End With` blocks, can lead to a very short, elegant (at least to me it does look like) and ***fast*** code, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BinValues()
    'binns seperation distance values for the creation of variogram       
    Dim K As Long, n As Long, L As Long

    n = 12
    L = 600
    With Worksheets("bins") '<--|refer to data sheet (change "bins" with your actual worksheet name
        .Cells(1, 1).Insert '<--|insert a temporary header cell: it'll be used for AutoFilter() method and eventually deleted
        .Cells(1, 1).value = "bin" '<--| place a dummy header in the temporary header cell            
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| refer columns "A" down to its last non empty row
            For K = L To (n * L) Step L
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & K - L, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & K '<--| filter it on current department value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Cells((K / L), 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(101, .Cells)
            Next K
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Cells(1, 1).Delete '<--| delete temporary header cell
    End With    
End Sub
```

which, even without any ScreenUpdating, Calculation or Events disabling runs much much faster than the one in Summary #1